# ng-repeat not working in script block

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to call a js function when an ng-repeat template is created:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input id="ip{{item.id}}">
  <script>$(function () { $('#ip{{item.id}}').kendoDatePicker(); });</script>
</div>
```

The  id is replaced as expected, but angular doesn't seem to work inside script tags.

Comment: why do you need to use it inside script tags

Comment: I'd recommend using the kendo angular tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, Angular will not evaluate expressions in `script` tags. You will need to use a directive that will initialize the Kendo plugin for each element.

The good news is [Kendo already has a module](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/) for integrating with Angular, so you might as well just use that. [Here is a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/tuKWySDkoJP64852DJFJ?p=preview) I put together showing it in a repeater.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <label for="{{item.id}}">{{item.id}}</label>
  <div>
    <input kendo-date-picker ng-model="item.value" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("demo", ['kendo.directives'])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [{
        id: 'item1',
        value: null
      }, {
        id: 'item2',
        value: null
      }, {
        id: 'item3',
        value: null
      }, {
        id: 'item4',
        value: null
      }];
    }
  ]);
```